# When mousing over a link I want the div that contains the link and other content to increase in height then back down to 19px on mouse out

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm customizing forum software

- each page has 20 threads
- each thread is contained inside a div whose `class="threadpreview"`
- inside of each "threadpreview" divs are the LINKs to the full thread, and a 500 character preview of the thread right beneath the link
- when the page loads up, I have all the divs' height set to 19px and overflow:hidden so that the preview of the thread is hidden and you can only see the LINK so the divs look "rolled up"
- when a user mouses over the LINK for that thread, the threadpreview div should "unroll" to it's original height to show the content, and `onmouseout` it should roll back up to 19px to hide the content.

(I'm not using jQuery)

EDIT: If jQuery can do this easily I'll give it a shot

[image]

Comment: I know that this could possibly be one of the most frustrating responses to any javascript related question on SO, but... have you considered jQuery? This would be a cross-browser compatible one-liner if you used it.

Comment: If you're a JavaScript noob, it would probably be more helpful to do this in JavaScript without jQuery.  Once you know JavaScript, then maybe use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should point you in the right direction:

```
function init() {
    var lDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = lDivs.length; i--;) {
        if(lDivs[i].className == "threadpreview") {
            lDivs[i].onmouseover = function() { this.style.height = ""; } // probably better to also use lDivs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", ..., false);
            lDivs[i].onmouseout = function() { this.style.height = "19px"; }
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false); // or window.attachEvent for IE, or window.onload = ...
```

You'll have to use the appropriate event-attachment function (or [switch between them](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-remove-elements-reprise/)).

Comment: This actually works but It makes the div expand when i mouseover anywhere on the div instead of the link. I'll do jquery if it's easier seeing as how I have no idea what an event attachment function is or which one I should use. I'll send some pay pal dollars to you, I just want to finally wrap this up.